# Load markers dynamically in flutter from another screen

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, maps

Screen A contains a google map which has a button that navigates the user to another screen (Screen B) where they can enter coordinates. Theses coords are stored in firestore and are used to build markers on the map. The back button on screen B is then pressed. I'd like the map to show the new marker. I could use a button to call `setState()` on the map screen but I don't want to do that. I'm also thinking of using a Streambuilder but not sure how I'd implement it with the marker class being a property of `GoogleMap()`. Any advice?
Here is my code:

```
class PlacesMap extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<PlacesMap> createState() => PlacesMapState();
}

class PlacesMapState extends State<PlacesMap> {

  GoogleMapController _mapController;
  Map<MarkerId, Marker> _markers = <MarkerId, Marker>{};

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _updateMarkers());
  }

  void _onMapCreated(GoogleMapController controller) {
    _updateMarkers();
    setState(() {
      _mapController = controller;
    });
  }

  void _updateMarkers() async {
    QuerySnapshot querySnapshot =
        await Firestore.instance.collection('position').getDocuments();
    List<DocumentSnapshot> documentList = querySnapshot.documents;
    _markers.clear();
    documentList.forEach((DocumentSnapshot document) {
      GeoPoint pos = document.data['geopoint'];
      print(pos.latitude.toString());
      print(pos.longitude.toString());
      String markerIdVal = document.documentID;

      final MarkerId markerId = MarkerId(markerIdVal);
      final Marker marker = Marker(
        markerId: markerId,
        position: LatLng(pos.latitude, pos.longitude),
      );

      setState(() {
        _markers[markerId] = marker;
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(children: [
      GoogleMap(
        initialCameraPosition:
            CameraPosition(target: LatLng(43.651070, -79.347015), zoom: 10),
        onMapCreated: _onMapCreated,
        compassEnabled: true,
        markers: Set<Marker>.of(_markers.values),
      ),
      Positioned(
        left: 100,
        bottom: 100,
        right: 100,
        child: RaisedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => AddressForm()),
            );
          },
          color: Colors.red,
          child: Text(
            'POST YOUR ADD',
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
          ),
        ),
      )
    ]);
  }
}
```

Comment: if you want to get the result from another `Route` check what `Navigator.push()` method returns

Answer (score 1):

thanks to @pskink for leading me to the answer. I was able to call `setState()` using the return from `Navigator.push()` to update the markers on the map screen

```
Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => AddressForm()),
            ).then((value){
              setState(() {
            _updateMarkers();
              });
            }
```

Comment: but honestly its a bit weird as you dont use `value` passed from the child page...

Comment: the value returned is null. And I don't use it. But I don't know how else I can call `setState`

Comment: ok i missed that part: *"Theses coords are stored in firestore and are used to build markers on the map."*